# Tried to resolve oh no something went wrong and now booting into Kodi…

Tags: boot

This relates to 21.04

I was stuck in a loop with oh no something went wrong as per various other request for help.

Tried going to a terminal and running update upgrade etc. Same issue on reboot. Noticed the option for login to different environments. Tried a few with same results.

Saw I had kodi as an option as a desktop environment and thought why not. Now the machine boots up to show an x for a cursor. Cannot seem to get back to the desktop login screen. Think this is kodi equivalent of oh no something went wrong?

Tried safe boot via grub by holding shift. Was presented with Ubuntu with Linux options 5.11.0-16 generic or 5.8.0-63 generic and the equivalent safe modes. 5.11 is same issues, 5.8 seems to boot me into a working copy of kodi. I don’t want kodi I want Ubuntu desktop…

I obviously have various problems but how can I think if I can change the default environment away from kodi I can get the machine to boot in 5.8 and make some progress.

Please be kind as I am trying to learn. Obviously mistakes were made. An option is to wipe and start from scratch but would like to fix this as a learning exercise.

Many thanks

Comment: Thank you! Can get to command line (Ctrl alt f1) via  5.11 (at what I think is failed kodi environment login) and it says Ubuntu 21.04 . Says 0 updates can be installed. Can I switch desktop environment from cli?

Comment: Ok so I still have the oh no something went wrong problem. The system was trying to boot into some sort of stand alone kodi environment. Fixed it by following the advice at the end of this discussion https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2383796

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Kodi login session by running the following commands:

```
cd /usr/share/xsessions  
sudo mv kodi.desktop kodi.desktop.bak
```